# How to route dynamically between tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have mat-tab angular app.And I want to get links dynamically and transfer to navLinks object.I did but it doesn't work.Its okay to give string like './1' for id parameter but I made concatanation and it doesnt work(I checked that concatenation is correct).Here's what I tried below

**TS File**

```
export class CarsComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks: any[];
  public href: string = "";
  activeLinkIndex = -1;
  mySubject;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {
        this.activeLinkIndex = this.navLinks.indexOf(this.navLinks.find(tab => tab.link === '.' + this.router.url));
    });
    this.mySubject=this.carService.carrierSubject.subscribe(value=>
      {
        this.id=value;
        let numid=this.id.toString();
        this.newString="./".concat(numid);
        console.log(this.newString);
      })
  }
  newString:string='';
  id:number;
  car:Car;
  constructor(private carService:CarService,private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) {
    this.navLinks = [
      {
          label: 'Preview',
          link:  this.newString,
          index: 0
      }, {
          label: 'Tuning',
          link: './tabtest2',
          index: 1
      }, {
          label: 'Payment',
          link: './tabtest3',
          index: 2
      }, 
  ];
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <app-car-list></app-car-list>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
            <a mat-tab-link
            *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
            [routerLink]="link.link"
            routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [active]="rla.isActive">
           {{link.label}}
          </a>
          </nav>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>     
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your implementation and get and error regarding the handling of the "routerLinkActive" (Angular 8.1.2). The following change in the template worked for me:

```
<a mat-tab-link 
  *ngFor="let link of navLinks" 
  [routerLink]="link.link" 
  routerLinkActive="active">

    {{ link.label }}

</a>
```

Angular adds an '.active' class automatically if a route is active. You can style an active route with your css afterwards.

Comment: What error do you get in your console and what angular version to you use?

Comment: I'm using as same as you're using.URL isn't recognizable and URL isn't changing when new URL comes

Comment: Could you sent me the error from your console? Maybe the routes are not bound in your router-configuration?

Comment: Please provide the error that is displayed in your browser console.